# Can't locate Android SDK installation directory for the AVD .ini file

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am getting this error when trying to create a new AVD:

[image]

This is the idea log file:

> 2022-04-05 14:01:12,132 [ 207201]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - com.android.prefs.AndroidLocationsException: Can't locate Android SDK installation directory for the AVD .ini file.

My Environment Variables are the following:

> ANDROID_AVD_HOME=E:\AndroidStudioSDK
>
> ANDROID_SDK_HOME=E:\AndroidStudioSDK
>
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=E:\AndroidStudioSDK

I don´t know which .ini file is looking for.

These are the SDK platforms installed:

[image]

This is what I have in SDK Tools:
[image]

I tried uninstalling and installing Android studio again with no different results.

How to fix this error?

by the way: I am not running any project, I simply want to create the Virtual Device.

Comment: What SDK Platforms do you already have installed?

Comment: @aspix I updated my question showing the SDK platforms installed.

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried creating a new AVD by using any other SDK Platform? For example, S or Pie

Comment: Thank you, I just tried Pie and S, I got the same error message.

Comment: Okay. Is proper Android SDK location shown in a Project Structure window? (cmd+; on Mac)

Comment: Yes, It says `E:\AndroidStudioSDK`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243626/discussion-between-aspix-and-stramin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get same alert because set error environment variables, the **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** not the sdk directory, change to .android directory may be useful, this my environment variables.

> ANDROID_AVD_HOME=D:\Android\.andorid\avd
>
> ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\Android\.android
>
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=D:\Android\Sdk

Comment: This answer works, If anyone needs more info, please check the chat where we solve it here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243626/discussion-between-aspix-and-stramin

Comment: This really wroks, thank you. Just a reminder - don't do programming in Windows (if you can)